Can we use Internal Combustion Engine exhaust to give heat for electrolysis to get hydrogen from water, to be used as fuel in the ICE?
Can we use exhaust from an Internal Combustion Engine to provide heat for the process of the electrolysis (to get hydrogen from water). And then use the H2 as fuel for the ICE so we use very little diesel, like -50%.  Not saying this is perpetual.
Does this setup even exist, already?

Certainly you can. The question is, how much valuable energy does that gain you, and how does that compare to the cost of all those additional systems?

How are you converting the exhaust heat into the electricity needed for electrolysis? Note that the energy produced by burning the hydrogen is equal to the energy needed to produce it, minus (inevitable) losses.

Sure it is possible, but would it make economic sense?

Yes, we can, but it would be of no use. When I was a child, I had the "ingenious" idea to power my bicycle by an electrical motor that would by driven be the dynamo used to power the electric globe. It wouldn't work because in each step energy is lost. Either by technical insufficiency or by principle physical reasons. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetuum_mobile

The catalytic converter can reach 1000F, from here.  This would be the place to extract your energy. Close to the cylinder heads, where the exhaust leaves the engine would be hotter, but there is not much space to mount anything there.
You could mount thermoelectric generators on the catalytic converter, which use the Seebeck effect to generate electricity. They also need a thermal dump (cold side), which could just be fins, which is another reason the catalytic converter is a better place to mount this.  These are very inefficient (5%-8%) (But remember, about 60% of the thermal energy from the fuel goes down that exhaust pipe) As the energy is free you just pay for initial cost of materials. Then you would also need somewhere to hydrolyze water into hydrogen and oxygen. Both of these gases could then be added to the air/fuel mix.
The best you could hope for from this arrangement is only a 3% improvement. You’d do MUCH better simply by improving your driving technique.
Aggressive driving increases fuel consumption by 15%-30% on the highway and even more in stop and go traffic.  see here
On the whole adding hydrogen to fuel, wherever the hydrogen comes from, does not have a good track record of efficiency improvement.see this wiki article

The general idea is physically sound.  As long as your exhaust is hotter than the outside environment, you can draw energy from it to do work.  What you describe is called a combined cycle engine.  Combined cycle engines are indeed some of the most efficient engines out there.
It would be more efficient to skip the electrolysis step all together.  Electrolysis is not 100% efficient, and burning the hydrogen in an ICE is probably 20% efficient or less.  Just use the work from the heat engine directly.
If it were practical, car manufacturer would have done it.  A more efficient heat engine would typically weigh more and take up more space.  The losses associated with that mass and space (adding drag) would likely offset any gains.  But that's an engineering problem, not a physics one.
In other environments, such as power plants, these disadvantages matter less. We do indeed see combined cycle engines in electrical power plants, and they do indeed have a high efficiency.

You can in principle use the wasted heat energy from the exhaust to increase the efficiency of an internal combustion engine. This is essentially what turbo charged engines do. The process of using the wasted heat to generate enough electricity for hydrolysis of water to hydrogen and somehow injecting this into the engine, probably has too many steps with incurred loses at each step, to be of any practical use.

Technically, yes, you could use the waste heat from an internal combustion engine (ICE) to provide heat for electrolysis. This process of splitting water into hydrogen and oxygen is called thermochemical electrolysis.
However, some key challenges make this approach impractical for widespread use:
Energy inefficiency: The overall system loses energy in the conversion steps. The energy used to run the ICE is first converted to mechanical work, then to heat, then to electricity for electrolysis, and finally back to mechanical work in the hydrogen-powered ICE. At each step, some energy is lost as waste heat.
Complexity: Adding electrolysis and heat recovery equipment to an existing ICE system significantly increases complexity and cost.
Limited benefit: In the end, you might not be achieving much overall reduction in fuel consumption. The energy used to create the hydrogen fuel is still derived from the original fuel source that powers the ICE.
There are more promising approaches to reducing emissions from internal combustion engines, such as improved engine efficiency and the development of cleaner-burning fuels.
For applications where electric vehicles are not suitable, hydrogen fuel cells are a more efficient way to utilize hydrogen as an energy carrier.  Fuel cells convert hydrogen directly into electricity, bypassing the inefficiencies of burning hydrogen in an engine.
